# What is reason when Google maps javascript API not work?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I handle geolocationError like below

```
function onerror(error) {
            switch(error){
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                      alert("Sinä sammutat paikannus tarkistus!");
                      break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                      alert("Ei pysty ottamaan sun paikannusta!");
                      break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                      alert("Aika loppu, lataa uudestaan!");
                      break;
                default:
                    alert("Tuntematon virhe!");
             }
        }
```

And when i run google maps in my app, i got the default error? I'm building google maps on Cordova Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, my Mac disable the location, weather service, it's small issue but took so much time from developer. Maybe it helps someone in the future.

http://neurogadget.net/2015/08/06/why-doesnt-google-maps-work-for-you-here-are-the-answers/11637